# Why does reversing a list work in LaTeX2e but not in LaTeX3?

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3

This is an extension of my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549141/tikz-foreach-loop-doesnt-work-when-the-list-is-reversed).

Here is the LaTeX2e version of my project code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xstring} % needed for \StrCount
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommandx{\tensormachinetwoe}[2][1]{%
  % For aesthetic reasons, we need to reverse the order of #1. 
  \let\revslots\empty
  \foreach \x in {#1}{%
    \ifx\revslots\empty
      \xdef\revslots{\x}
    \else
      \xdef\revslots{\x,\revslots}
    \fi
  }%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\slotwidth}{1}

    % front
    \draw[fill=white,thick] (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey,0.5*\cubez) -- 
      ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle
      % label the machine
      node at (0.30*\cubex,0,0.5*\cubez) {\(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#2}}\)};
    % side
    \draw[fill=white,thick] (0.5*\cubex,0.5\cubey,-0.5*\cubez) --    
      ++(0,0,\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- cycle;
    % top
    \draw[fill=white,thick] (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey,-0.5*\cubez) --
      ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    % output slot
    \draw[fill=black, ultra thick] (-0.5*\slotwidth,0,0.5*\cubez) -- 
      ++(0,0.03,0) -- ++(\slotwidth,0,0) -- ++(0,-0.03,0) -- cycle;
    %\fill (0,0,0) circle (2pt); % origin
    
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
      {% We have a scalar. Fill the output slot and we're done.
        \draw[fill=white, thin,-] (-0.5*\slotwidth+0.1,0,0.5*\cubez) 
          -- ++(-0.25,-\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) 
          -- ++(0.25,\slotwidth,0) 
          node at (-0.125*\slotwidth,-0.5*\cubey,0.5*\cubez) {\(\mathbb{R}\)};
      }%
      {% We have slots, which may be filled or unfilled.
        % Set some values.
        \StrCount{#1,}{,}[\numslots]
        \StrCount{#1}{+}[\numfilledslots]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startvslotx}{-0.25*\cubex-0.5*\slotwidth}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startoslotx}{+0.25*\cubex-0.5*\slotwidth}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\sloty}{0.5*\cubey}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnumslots}{\numslots}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\slotspace}{\cubez / (\totalnumslots + 1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\islotspaceindex}{1}
        % Loop through the reversed list of slots.
        \foreach \currentslot in \revslots {%
          \IfBeginWith{\currentslot}{v}%
            {% Draw a vector slot.
              \draw[fill=black, ultra thick]
                (\startvslotx,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                -- ++(0,0,0.04) -- ++(\slotwidth,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-0.04) -- cycle;
              % Test to see if we need to fill the slot.
              \IfEndWith{\currentslot}{+}%
                {% Fill the slot.
                  \draw[fill=white,thin]
                   (\startvslotx+0.1,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                   -- ++(0,\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) -- ++(0,-\slotwidth,0);
                }%
                {% Leave it empty.
                }%
            }%
            {% Draw a 1-form slot.
              \draw[fill=black, ultra thick]
                (\startoslotx,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                -- ++(0,0,0.04) -- ++(\slotwidth,0,0)-- ++(0,0,-0.04) -- cycle; 
              % Test to see if we need to fill the slot.
              \IfEndWith{\currentslot}{+}%
                {% Fill the slot.
                  \draw[fill=lightgray,thin]
                    (\startoslotx+0.1,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                    -- ++(0,\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) -- ++(0,-\slotwidth,0);
                }%
                {% Leave it empty.
                }%
            }%
          \pgfmathparse{\islotspaceindex+1}
          \xdef\islotspaceindex{\pgfmathresult}
        }%
        % Test to see if we need to fill the output slot.
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\numslots}{\numfilledslots}}%
        {% Fill the output slot.
          \draw[fill=white, thin,-] (-0.5*\slotwidth+0.1,0,0.5*\cubez) 
             -- ++(-0.25,-\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) 
             -- ++(0.25,\slotwidth,0) 
             node at (-0.125*\slotwidth,-0.5*\cubey,0.5*\cubez) {\(\mathbb{R}\)};
        }%
        {% Leave it empty.
        }%
      }%
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
\[
\tensormachinetwoe[v,o]{T}
\]
\[
\tensormachinetwoe[o+,v+]{T}
\]
\[
\tensormachinetwoe[o+,o+,v+]{T}
\]
\[
\tensormachinetwoe{}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here is the LaTeX3 version of the same project:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3} % seems to be optional
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring} % needed for \StrCount
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tensormachinetwoe}{ m O{} O{} }{%
  % For aesthetic reasons, we need to reverse the order of #1. 
  \clist_clear_new:N \revslots
  \clist_set:Nn \revslots {\clist_reverse:n #1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\slotwidth}{1}

    % front
    \draw[fill=white,thick] (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey,0.5*\cubez) -- 
      ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle
      % label the machine
      node at (-0.30*\cubex,0,0.5*\cubez) {\(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#2}}\)}
      node at (0.30*\cubex,0,0.5*\cubez) {\(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#3}}\)};
    % side
    \draw[fill=white,thick] (0.5*\cubex,0.5\cubey,-0.5*\cubez) --    
      ++(0,0,\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- cycle;
    % top
    \draw[fill=white,thick] (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey,-0.5*\cubez) --
      ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    % output slot
    \draw[fill=black, ultra~thick] (-0.5*\slotwidth,0,0.5*\cubez) -- 
      ++(0,0.03,0) -- ++(\slotwidth,0,0) -- ++(0,-0.03,0) -- cycle;
    %\fill (0,0,0) circle (2pt); % origin
    
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
      {% We have a scalar. Fill the output slot and we're done.
        \draw[fill=white, thin,-] (-0.5*\slotwidth+0.1,0,0.5*\cubez) 
          -- ++(-0.25,-\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) 
          -- ++(0.25,\slotwidth,0) 
          node at (-0.125*\slotwidth,-0.5*\cubey,0.5*\cubez) {\(\mathbb{R}\)};
      }%
      {% We have slots, which may be filled or unfilled.
        % Set some values.
        \StrCount{#1,}{,}[\numslots]
        \StrCount{#1}{+}[\numfilledslots]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startvslotx}{-0.25*\cubex-0.5*\slotwidth}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startoslotx}{+0.25*\cubex-0.5*\slotwidth}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\sloty}{0.5*\cubey}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnumslots}{\numslots}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\slotspace}{\cubez / (\totalnumslots + 1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\islotspaceindex}{1}
        % Loop through the reversed list of slots.
        \foreach \currentslot in \revslots {%
          %\node at (4,0,0) {\currentslot}; % debug
          \IfBeginWith{\currentslot}{v}%
            {% Draw a vector slot.
              \draw[fill=black, ultra~thick]
                (\startvslotx,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                -- ++(0,0,0.04) -- ++(\slotwidth,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-0.04) -- cycle;
              % Test to see if we need to fill the slot.
              \IfEndWith{\currentslot}{+}%
                {% Fill the slot.
                  \draw[fill=white,thin]
                   (\startvslotx+0.1,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                   -- ++(0,\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) -- ++(0,-\slotwidth,0);
                }%
                {% Leave it empty.
                }%
            }%
            {% Draw a 1-form slot.
              \draw[fill=black, ultra~thick]
                (\startoslotx,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                -- ++(0,0,0.04) -- ++(\slotwidth,0,0)-- ++(0,0,-0.04) -- cycle; 
              % Test to see if we need to fill the slot.
              \IfEndWith{\currentslot}{+}%
                {% Fill the slot.
                  \draw[fill=lightgray,thin]
                    (\startoslotx+0.1,\sloty,-0.5*\cubez+\islotspaceindex*\slotspace) 
                    -- ++(0,\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) -- ++(0,-\slotwidth,0);
                }%
                {% Leave it empty.
                }%
            }%
          \pgfmathparse{\islotspaceindex+1}
          \xdef\islotspaceindex{\pgfmathresult}
        }%
        % Test to see if we need to fill the output slot.
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\numslots}{\numfilledslots}}%
        {% Fill the output slot.
          \draw[fill=white, thin,-] (-0.5*\slotwidth+0.1,0,0.5*\cubez) 
             -- ++(-0.25,-\slotwidth,0) -- ++(\slotwidth-0.2,0,0) 
             -- ++(0.25,\slotwidth,0) 
             node at (-0.125*\slotwidth,-0.5*\cubey,0.5*\cubez) {\(\mathbb{R}\)};
        }%
        {% Leave it empty.
        }%
      }%
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
\tensormachinetwoe{v,o}[T]
\]
\[
\tensormachinetwoe{o+,v+}[T]
\]
\[
\tensormachinetwoe{o+,o+,v+}[T]
\]
\[
\tensormachinetwoe{}
\]
\end{document}
```

The results must be identical, and they almost are. In the LaTeX3 version, the slots on the top of the machine are drawn in the reverse order in which they need to be drawn despite having been reversed at the very beginning of the `\tensormachinetwoe` function as in the LaTeX2e version. If, in the LaTeX3 version, I change the line `\clist_set:Nn \revslots {\clist_reverse:n #1}` to `\clist_set:Nn \revslots {\clist_reverse:n {#1}}` the first slot is drawn in the correct place but subsequent ones aren't drawn. There are no error messages. Am I missing something obvious in the LaTeX3 version?

Comment: TikZ code inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` is a no-go,because spaces are ignored.

Comment: @egreg So there's absolutely no way around that, and what I need to do is impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ti*k*Z code under `\ExplSyntaxOn` is impossible, because spaces get ignored.

You just need to define a “reversal” command:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\reverselist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:N #1
  \clist_set:Nx #1 { \clist_reverse:n { #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and start your code outside of `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Change all `ultra~thick` to `ultra thick`.

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\tensormachinetwoe}{ m O{} O{} }{%
  % For aesthetic reasons, we need to reverse the order of #1. 
  \reverselist{\revslots}{#1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  [...]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was very close. I had tried creating a separate "reversal" command, but with only one argument, not two. I don't think I can show the code block in a comment, but I was close. Thanks again.